# Errors with tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I'm trying to use `tocloft` to create a list of equations in the contents table of my thesis, but it's erroring when I compile the document. I've used `\newcounter` to define a new list of R scripts for the appendices, and it seems that this new counter is not compatible with `tocloft`.

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
  \usepackage{anysize,array,multirow,graphicx,epstopdf,natbib,caption,color,hhline,symlist,amsmath,acronym,subfig,listings,placeins,hyperref,wrapfig,rotating,tocloft} 
  \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
  \marginsize{3cm}{3cm}{2cm}{2cm}

  \captionsetup[table]{skip=4pt,font=footnotesize} %works with package{caption} to skip the height from the table, and to select 10pt as the text size 
  \captionsetup[figure]{skip=4pt,font=footnotesize} %works with package{caption} to skip the height from the table, and to select 10pt as the text size 

  \DeclareCaptionType{equationme}[][List of Equations] %this is a work-around to get a list of equations with page numbers in my contents page, however it adds a caption to my equations (not ideal!!)
  \captionsetup[equationme]{skip=4pt,font=footnotesize}

  \newlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}

  \newcommand{\Cline}[2]{%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}{\arrayrulewidth}}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{#1}}\cline{#2}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\Oldarrayrulewidth}}}

 %this is the R bit............
  \newcounter{Script}[section]
  \newenvironment{Script}[1][]{\refstepcounter{Script}\par\medskip
  \textbf{Script~\theScript. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}


  \begin{document}

  \listofequationme
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Equations}

  \begin{equationme}[!ht]
  \caption[Earthquake magnitude affect on landsliding]{Relationship between earthquake magnitude and the potential area affected by landsliding as defined by \hilight{Keefer}, where A' is the potential area affected.}
      \begin{equation}
      \label{eq:EQMagnitudelsArea}
      log_{10} \newsym{Potential area affected}{A'} = \newsym{Earthquake magnitude}{M}-3.46(\pm0.47)
      \end{equation}
  \end{equationme}

  \end{document}
```

While the list works fine for the equations, I don't want to have to have a caption above it... So can someone either tell me how to edit `\captionsetup` or how to get `tocloft` to work alongside the `\newcounter{Script}[section]` command as this is where I seem to be getting an error...

Error is:

```
Command \c@lotdepth already defined. \newcounter{lotdepth}
```

I really hope this makes sense as I'm going a little loopy right now!

Comment: Please provide all information: What is `symlist.sty`? Where can we find it?

Comment: `subfig` package is to blame. Since you don't need it, remove it

Comment: beware `\global\setlength` it is not supported syntax, it sort of accidentally works by default but if `calc` package (at least) is loaded then this will fail.

Comment: So firstly, sorry for not including the things...

Christian
Here is a link to [symlist.sty](http://www.utdallas.edu/~hamlen/symlist.sty). 
I do need the `subfig` package as I'm including this later in the thesis (I wasn't about to upload all of the document, and I wasn't sure how much I needed to upload...).
David
I'm not sure about the `\global\setlength` syntax... Is this something you think I need to address?

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is the loading order of `subfig` and `tocloft`.

`subfig` defines `c@lotdepth` by a `\@nameuse` statement - as such it's already defined at the time when `tocloft` tries to setup this new counter.

The same is true for `c@lofdepth`, leading to a similar error.

The other way round, using `tocloft` first before loading `subfig` poses no problem.

Another solution is to remove the loading of `subfig` -- it's apparently not used in the 'MWE'

(I also cleaned up the document, slightly)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{symlist}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\marginsize{3cm}{3cm}{2cm}{2cm}

% Unused
%\captionsetup[table]{skip=4pt,font=footnotesize} %works with package{caption} to skip the height from the table, and to select 10pt as the text size 
%\captionsetup[figure]{skip=4pt,font=footnotesize} %works with package{caption} to skip the height from the table, and to select 10pt as the text size 

\DeclareCaptionType{equationme}[][List of Equations] %this is a work-around to get a list of equations with page numbers in my contents page, however it adds a caption to my equations (not ideal!!)
\captionsetup[equationme]{skip=4pt,font=footnotesize}

\newlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}

\newcommand{\Cline}[2]{%
  \noalign{\setlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}{\arrayrulewidth}}%
  \noalign{\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{#1}}\cline{#2}%
  \noalign{\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\Oldarrayrulewidth}}}

% this is the R bit............
\newcounter{Script}[section]
\newenvironment{Script}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{Script}\par\medskip
  \textbf{Script~\theScript. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}


\providecommand{\hilight}[1]{%
  #1%
}

\begin{document}

\listofequationme
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Equations}

\begin{equationme}[!ht]
  \caption[Earthquake magnitude affect on landsliding]{Relationship between earthquake magnitude and the potential area affected by landsliding as defined by \hilight{Keefer}, where A' is the potential area affected.}
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:EQMagnitudelsArea}
    log_{10} \newsym{Potential area affected}{A'} = \newsym{Earthquake magnitude}{M}-3.46(\pm0.47)
  \end{equation}
\end{equationme}

\end{document}
```

[image]